# How to teach latex to find Sweave.sty? [Ubuntu 12.04; TeXLive 2011]

Tags: texlive, sweave

I work on XUbuntu 12.04 and I have installed `R 2.15`. Since the package manager only provides TeX Live 2009, I use the following to install TeX Live 2011 on XUbuntu:

1. download `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` from [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)
2. `tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz`
3. `sudo ./install-tl` # see [TeX Live - Quick install](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) (hit "I")
4. add the newly installed version to `PATH` (in `.profile`):

   ```
   PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
   ```

Whenever I compile a `.tex` document containing `\usepackage{Sweave}`, I obtain

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: File 'Sweave.sty' not found.
```

Typically, one uses a symbolic link to teach `(pdf)latex` (actually, `latexmk` in my case) where to find `Sweave.sty`. I did the following:

```
cd /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/tex/latex # that's the tex tree obtained by kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFMAIN
sudo ln -s /usr/share/R/share/texmf Sweave
```

I also created a link named `Sweave` in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex` (via `sudo ln -s /usr/share/R/share/texmf Sweave`). In both cases, I still obtain that `Sweave.sty` was not found (even after a `reboot/texhash`...).

How can I tell `pdflatex` where to find `Sweave.sty`?

If you need more information about my setup of `R` etc., just let me know.

**FINAL SOLUTION**

Alan's answer below is completely correct. The reason why `Sweave.sty` was not found in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex` is that I installed TeXLive 2011 via `sudo` and so I also had to execute `mktexlsr` via `sudo`. The problem is (see `sudo which mktexlsr` vs `which mktexlsr`) that `sudo mktexlsr` updates only the *old* (2009) TeXLive tex tree. I found two posts that precisely address this (http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/texlive-not-searching-texmflocal/266185 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1843563). The final solution is to `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/local/texlive`. Then one can simply use `mktexlsr` (without `sudo`) to update the new (2011) TeXLive tex tree. Then, `Sweave.sty` is found as Alan described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your link isn't found is that additions to the main texmf tree require the ls-R databases to be updated using `mktexlsr`.  However, the usual place for local additions on a Linux system is `~/texmf`.  If you put your symbolic link in `~/texmf/tex/latex`, then you won't need do anything else for it to be found.

You should never place files in any of the `.../texlive/<year>` directories, since they are for the actual distribution files and can be overwritten by updates.

If you truly need system-wide local additions (for multiple users) you can put them in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`.  If you put things here, you must run `sudo mktexlsr` to rebuild the ls-R databases.

Comment: Dear Alan, thanks for helping. Your first solution (`~/texmf/tex/latex`) works (which is good). Your second solution unfortunately doesn't work. I put the link once in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and in a second trial in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex', neither worked (after `sudo mktexlsr`). Do you know why? Ideally, I would prefer the second solution since it does not clutter my `~`. I also found `~/.texlive2011`, put in a subfolder `/tex/latex/`, and created the link from in there, but again, `Sweave.sty` was not found.

Comment: @Marius Putting the link in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex` + `mktexlsr` should have worked. That's how my system is set up.  (I'm using a Mac, but that shouldn't make a difference in this case.)  What does `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` return on your system?

Comment: Dear Alan, thanks again for helping. It returns `/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local`, which -- when I `cd` in that directory -- gives me `pwd`: `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`

Comment: I tested another thing: I copied `Sweave.sty` in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex` (then executed `mktexlsr`). But even then it wasn't found.

Comment: Can it be that `mktexlsr` does not work correctly? I obtain:

    mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
    mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
    mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE... 
    mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
    mktexlsr: Done.

Comment: Indeed, `mktexlsr` was the problem. I executed it as root all the time. But `sudo which mktexlsr` in contrast to `which mktexlsr` updates the *old* tex tree (the TeXLive 2009 version), not the TeXLive 2011 version. So the final solution was to first set the correct owner via `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /usr/local/texlive` and then to use `mktexlsr` (instead of sudo `mktexlsr`).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the status to comment, but would like to add one thing for posterity:

If in the above you would have wanted to run the 2011 `mktexlsr` with sudo, then what you can do (also to update with tlmgr where the same problem occurs if you have an older installation) is to cd into the `../2012/bin/x86_64-linux` folder and execute de binary directly from there.

So you would see something like:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux $ sudo ./mktexlsr
```

or

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux $ sudo ./tlmgr
```

(in my case I have 2011 and 2011 installed, hence the foldername above).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)